# Start and finish section with black triangle

Tags: latex, tex

i need to make an article and i want to start and end 1 section (theorem for example) with triangles like this:
[start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Oo6.png)

[end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjkj1.png)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you write your theorem and proof as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{lemma}
Given ......
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
Assume that.....
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

you only need to redefine the end of proof symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacktriangle$}

\begin{document}
\begin{lemma}
Given ......
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
Assume that.....
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

It's the `\renewcommand` that does the trick. You can use it elswhere aswell.

Comment: what about starting a proof with symbol?

Comment: Try simply adding $\blacktriangle$